# Make form URL submission look like route instead of query string

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

Is there a way to change default URL formation on form submission?

Here is what I have:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url('some_controller/some_method'); ?>" method="GET">
    <select name="foo">
        <option value="1">bar</option>
        <option value="2">Wubba lubba dub dub</option>
    </select>
    <button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

When I click the button, the url becomes: (**not wanted**)

```
localhost/some_controller/some_method?foo=2
```

Is there a way to make it like the following? (**expected result**)

```
localhost/some_controller/some_method/2
```

Is it achievable with PHP / Codeigniter only? Or maybe in HTML?
*(Can it be done without javascript and without htaccess?)*

I don't think using the `form_open` method makes any difference.

Comment: Why not just use POST instead of GET?

Comment: @BrianGottier for freeeeedom. No, but seriously. For this:

Comment: Well then your answer is no, it is not possible. You can't manipulate the HTML output by PHP after it is sent to the browser. You would have to use javascript.

Comment: _Here is a detailed context:_ I have a previous page with a list of anchors for that method that passes the value as GET. That list and this form have the same purpose. Using it the way I expected, I can use the same method without changing anything inside the method itself. I could refactor it to use the parameter or POST data, or even send this form as POST to another method and in there just call the other method passing the value just like the list does. But I was curious if it was possible... @BrianGottier

Comment: I've enjoyed thinking on the possibility, but I agree with @BrianGottier.  The value isn't known until the user submits the page.  However, couldn't you create a handler that would redirect them to your `localhost/some_controller/some_method/2` after they submit?

Comment: Yeah, that's one of the solutions I thought and was kinda trying to avoid xD. @bc2946088

Comment: @FirstOne To clarify, your problem isn't a PHP or codeigniter problem.  The fact that your form input ends up in your URL is 100% the default browser behavior in response to form with a request method of `GET`.  The only way you can get the form URL to change on the basis of input is with javascript.  Think about your expected result: how is the browser supposed to know that your `foo` input variable is supposed to turn into part of the submit URL?  It simply can't, which is why you need javascript, or have to do a POST submit to hide the data from the URL.

Comment: I won't drag this long: You said _how is the browser supposed to know..._ How does the browser know, eg, where to send form data to? Basically we tell it with `action`. My question could be translated to: is there a way to _tell_ the browser to send the query string this given way? Edit: my point is, the browser does things we tell it to do (kinda) @ConorMancone

Comment: @FirstOne Absolutely: it knows where to send the request because of the action parameter.  However, what you are (effectively) trying to do is allow the action parameter to vary depending on the input.  HTML isn't designed to support that use-case: the action comes in through the `action` attribute, which is a fixed string.  The only way to make it dynamic is with javascript.

Comment: @FirstOne:: Javascrit is the media to talk with browser in client end. As you are expecting to talk with browser Javascript is the only way.

Comment: Edit question and show code where this url is created `localhost/some_controller/some_method?foo=2`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 What? That specific URL is not created anywhere in the code, really. It's a combination of codeigniter's [base_url](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#base_url) function inside the form's `action` and the query string from form submission. If I were the one creating it, I wouldn't be asking this question xD

Answer (score 0):

This happens because your method is `GET`.  If you change your method to `POST` the info will disappear out of the URL.  However, it will have different side-effects which are either good or bad depending on your viewpoint:

1. Post will put it in scope for CSRF protection, if that is turned on in codeigniter.
2. You will get a "Do you want to resubmit?"-type of message from your browser if navigating back to a page that was the result of a POST submit.

The only other alternative is to do an ajax request in the background via javascript.

Comment: I already thought of some alternative solutions for this, but I was hoping to find an answer showing how to do it the expected way.